# Perl warning: "Found = in conditional, should be ==", but there's no equals sign on the line

Tags: perl, warnings

I am running the following in Perl v5.12.3 on [Mac OS X v10.7.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:testdrive.db") or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my @times = ("13:00","14:30","16:00","17:30","19:00","20:30","22:00");

my $counter = 1;

for (my $d = 1; $d < 12; $d++) {
    for (my $t = 0; $t < 7; $t++) {
        # Weekend days have seven slots, weekdays
        # have only four (barring second friday)
        if (($d+4) % 7 < 2 || ($t > 3)) {
            $db->do("INSERT INTO tbl_timeslot VALUES ($counter, '$times[$t]', $d);");
            $counter++;
        # Add 4:00 slot for second Friday
        } elsif (($d = 9) && ($t = 3)) {
            $db->do("INSERT INTO tbl_timeslot VALUES ($counter, '$times[$t]', $d);");
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}

$db->disconnect;
```

I get a "Found = in conditional, should be == at addtimes.pl line 16" warning, but there's no equal sign on that line. Also, the loop seems to start at `$d == 9`.  What am I missing?

Line 16:

```
if (($d+4) % 7 < 2 || ($t > 3)) {
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is in your `elsif`

```
} elsif (($d = 9) && ($t = 3)) {
             ^-----------^--------- should be ==
```

Because the `if` statement started on line 16, and the `elsif` is part of that statement, that's where the error got reported from. This is an unfortunate limitation of the Perl compiler.

On an unrelated note, it's much nicer to avoid C-style loops when you can:

```
for my $d ( 1 .. 11 ) { 
    ...
    for my $t ( 0 .. 6 ) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Isn't that prettier? :)

Comment: Didn't think to look at lines below 16. Thanks!

Comment: The original loops were `1 .. 11` and `0 .. 6`.  (Although he probably _meant_ to do `1 .. 12` and `0 .. 6`.  Or `0 .. $#times`.)

Comment: Actually, 1 .. 11 is correct. And yes, those loops look prettier - thanks for the syntax help.

Answer (score 6):

```
} elsif (($d = 9) && ($t = 3)) {
```

This line will assign `9` to `$d` and `3` to `$t`. As the warning says, you probably want this instead:

```
} elsif (($d == 9) && ($t == 3)) {
```